# Is there any other way to repaint from another class?

Tags: java, repaint

I'm trying to repaint() from another class. I know one way to do this:

```
//FromClass.java:
SomeClass whatever = new SomeClass(this);

    //SomeClass.java:
        FromClass f;
        public SomeClass(FromClass from){ //constructor
        f = from;
    }
    //after a long part of code
    f.repaint();
```

Is there any other way to do this, without any parameters in class constructor?
And sorry for my technical English, still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to share information between classes. I believe that the method you demonstrated is the most effective. Here are some other options:

- Make `SomeClass` a subclass of `FromClass` so that it inherits all of the methods defined in `FromClass`. Then create an instance of `FromClass` and call methods on the variable. Your class declaration would look like this:

  ```
  class SomeClass extends FromClass {
      ...
      super.repaint();  
      ....
  ```
- Make `FromClass` an interface and implement it:

  ```
  public interface FromClass {
      void repaint();
  }

  class SomeClass implements FromClass {
      repaint();
  ```

Just some other alternatives. :)